# how to find index of String Array accepted by user in java?

Tags: java, arrays, string

Accept the string from user eg:[Aamir,Hrithik,Salman]
Now when i pass Hrithik it should return its index?
How?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int str,i;
    String check;
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter string array size: ");
    str=sc.nextInt();
    String arr[]= new String[str];
    System.out.println("Enter elements for String array: ");

    for(i=0;i<str;i++)
    {
        arr[i] = sc.next();
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

    System.out.println("Enter the name to check index of it:");
    check=sc.next();
    if(arr[i].equals(check))
    {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying your code doesn't work?

Comment: `Arrays.asList(arr).indexOf(check)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking a single element of the array `arr[i].equals(check)` doesn't help much. Note that `i` hasn't been reset from the previous loop execution, you might get an invalid array index (`i >= arr.length`).

You'd better iterate over all the elements of the array to look for a match:

```
for(i = 0; i < str; ++i) {
    if (arr[i].equals(check)) {
        System.out.println(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to return the index of a value inside an array. You can:

Use a loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < str; i++) {
    if (arr[i].equals(check)) {
        System.out.println("Index of value: " + i);
        break; 
    }
}
```

Use the [`Arrays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) utility class:

```
System.out.println("Index of value: " + Arrays.asList(arr).indexOf(check));
```

Use the Apache Commons Lang [`ArrayUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html) class:

```
System.out.println("Index of value: " + ArrayUtils.indexOf(arr, check));
```

Answer (score 0):

Transform the array to a list then use `indexOf` method.

```
    String[] arr = {"Aamir","Hrithik","Salman"};
    String target = "Hrithik";
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(arr).indexOf(target));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a for loop at the end to loop through the entire array. The following code should work. I have also made some other edits that make the code generally better.

Side note: you should format your code a bit better to make it more readable. On most IDEs, you can auto format code using CTRL/CMD+SHIFT+F .

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int str, i;
    String check;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter string array size: ");
    str = sc.nextInt();

    String arr[] = new String[str];
    System.out.println("Enter elements for String array: ");

    for (i = 0; i < str; i++) {
        arr[i] = sc.next();
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("Enter the name to check index of it:");
    check = sc.next();

    for (int j = 0; j < str; j++) {
        if (arr[j].equals(check)) {
            System.out.println(j);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```